# nodejs script execute every 6 hours

Tags: node.js

I have this script using the npm module [`node-shedule`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule). I think I set it to run every 6 hours but it runs for an hour when the hour is 0,6,12,18. it only may run once. I could dirty fix it with a bool, but that ain't my style.

a cronjob in Linux is not an option either, it needs to run cross-platform

```
let schedule = require('node-schedule'); 
let j = schedule.scheduleJob('* */6 * * *', function() {
do smt
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will run every minute. Change cron schedule to `0 */6 * * *`, to only run it when the minute is 0.

Comment: its probably a mistake on my side, in my console it works, but on my rpi it does not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do:

```
let schedule = require('node-schedule'); 

let j = nodeSchedule.scheduleJob('0 0 */5 * * *', function() {
  do smt
});
```

It will run in the second 0 minute 0 every 6 hours.
They use this [format](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule#cron-style-scheduling)

```
*    *    *    *    *    *
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │    |
│    │    │    │    │    └ day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)
│    │    │    │    └───── month (1 - 12)
│    │    │    └────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    │    └─────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│    └──────────────────── minute (0 - 59)
└───────────────────────── second (0 - 59, optional)
```

Comment: will try this. gonna see in 6 hours!